# Why am I getting a run time error in Google code jam?

Tags: java, runtime

Vestigium means "trace" in Latin. In this problem, we work with Latin squares and matrix traces.
The trace of a square matrix is the sum of the values on the main diagonal (which runs from the upper left to the lower right).
An N-by-N square matrix is a Latin square if each cell contains one of N different values, and no value is repeated within a row or a column. In this problem, we will deal only with "natural Latin squares" in which the N values are the integers between 1 and N.
Given a matrix that contains only integers between 1 and N, we want to compute its trace and check whether it is a natural Latin square. To give some additional information, instead of simply telling us whether the matrix is a natural Latin square or not, please compute the number of rows and the number of columns that contain repeated values.

It runs in Intellij

```
class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=sc.nextInt();
        for(int z=1;z<=T;z++)
        {

            int size=sc.nextInt();
            int mat[][]=new int[size][size];

            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
                {
                    mat[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                }
            }

            int k=trace(mat,size);

            int r=row_duplicate(mat,size);

            int c=col_duplicate(mat,size);

            System.out.println("Case #" +z+ ":"+" " +k+ " " +r+ " " +c); //Case #1: 4 0 0
        }
    }

    public static int trace(int arr[][],int size)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                if(i==j)
                    sum=sum+arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static int row_duplicate(int arr[][],int size)
    {
        Hashtable<Integer,Integer> h=new Hashtable<>();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            int row[]=arr[i];
            for(int j=0;j<row.length;j++)
            {
                if(h.containsKey(row[j]))
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    h.put(row[j],1);
                }
            }
            h.clear();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int col_duplicate(int arr[][],int size)
    {
        Hashtable<Integer,Integer> h=new Hashtable<>();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                int ele=arr[j][i];
                if(h.containsKey(ele))
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    h.put(ele,1);
                }
            }
            h.clear();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the text of the error? Any stack trace?

Comment: `Hashtable` is not recommended by [the docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html)  Use `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: the thing that you should take from this: SO is not a homework service. How to ask a question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . How to post code -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should mention your class name 'Solution'.
for further information go through the [link](https://code.google.com/codejam/resources/faq)

Comment: Yes without the Solution class it will throw a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not importing Scanner class properly.
Add this line at the top: `import java.util.*;`

Comment: No, the import was in the code. I removed it in my edit as it goes without saying. Also, the first line "class Main {" could be removed because it's understood

Comment: People rarely post imports. Usually, they post methods and other essential lines like stack traces

Comment: And the line import java.util.* was hidden by code ticks ```, it happens when text is typed after ticks in one line. Code should start in the next line after the ticks

Answer (score 0):

Change the class name to Solution instead of Main

i.e

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        
        int k =1;
        while(t > 0)
        {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
        
            int m[][] = new int[n][n];
            int rows = 0, columns = 0;  
            for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < n ;j++)
                {
                    m[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }
            
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                sum+= m[i][i];
            }
            
            for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                HashSet<Integer> h = new HashSet<>();
                for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
                {
                    h.add(m[i][j]);
                }
                if(h.size() < n)
                {
                    rows++;
                }
            }
            
            for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                HashSet<Integer> h = new HashSet<>();
                for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
                {
                    h.add(m[j][i]);
                }
                if(h.size() < n)
                {
                    columns++;
                }
            }
            
            System.out.printf("Case #%d: %d %d %d\n", k, sum, rows, columns);
            k++;
            t--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the python implementation of the code, this is working for all the test cases
feel free to ask if you encounter an issue

```
T = int(input())
for i in range(1,T+1):
    size=int(input())
    column =[]
    r = 0
    c = 0
    k = 0
    for a in range(size):
        row = list(map(int,input().split()))
        column.append(row)
    for q in range(size):
        k=k+column[q][q]
    for q in column:
        for z in q:
            if q.count(z)>1:
                r = r+1
                break
    column = [[column[j][i] for j in range(len(column))] for i in range(len(column[0]))]

    for q in column:
        for z in q:
            if q.count(z)>1:
                c = c+1
                break
    i=str(i)
    print("Case #"+i+":",k,r,c)
```